# Incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)

Tags: java, generics, java-8, typechecking

I was implementing some architecture when I saw the following error:

```or-tag-here
Error:(33, 55) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: java.io.Serializable
    upper bound(s): sandbox.ExpirePolicy,java.io.Serializable
```

The whole simplified code is below:

```or-tag-here
interface Configuration<K,V>{}
interface ExpirePolicy{}
interface Factory<T>{}


class FactoryBuilder {
    public static <T extends Serializable> Factory<T> of(T instance){
        System.out.println(instance.getClass());
        return new Factory<T>() {};
    }
}

class BaseConfiguration<K,V> implements Configuration<K,V> {
    public BaseConfiguration<K,V> setExpiryPolicyFactory(Factory<? extends ExpirePolicy> factory){
        return this;
    }
}

class C<K,V> extends BaseConfiguration<K,V> {
    public C<K,V> setExpiration(){
        super.setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.of((Serializable) getExpirePolicy()));
        return this;
    }

    private ExpirePolicy getExpirePolicy(){
        return new ExpirePolicy() {};
    }
}
```

The exception is in trying to call `setExpiryPolicyFactory(Factory<? extends ExpirePolicy> factory)` with instance of `Factory<Serializable>`

But if i delete generic in `extends BaseConfiguration<K,V>` the program will be successfully compiled.

So the next declaration of class C is correct:

```or-tag-here
class C<K,V> extends BaseConfiguration {
    public C<K,V> setExpiration(){
        super.setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.of((Serializable) getExpirePolicy()));
        return this;
    }

    private ExpirePolicy getExpirePolicy(){
        return new ExpirePolicy() {};
    }
}
```

**The question is: why the second implementation(of class `C`) will be successfully compiled and the first not?**

**UPD:**

Simpler example of question (delete `<T>` from `extends Base<T>`) and program compiles well :

```or-tag-here
class Base<T> {
    public void test(ArrayList<? extends CharSequence> list) {}
}

class Derived<T> extends Base<T> {
    public void callTest() {
        super.test(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you delete `<T>` from `extends Base<T>` statement, the `Base` class starts to be treated as a *raw type*.

According to [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The supertype of a class may be a raw type. Member accesses for the
>   class are treated as normal, and member accesses for the supertype are
>   treated as for raw types. In the constructor of the class, calls to
>   super are treated as method calls on a raw type.

This means that `super.test(...)` call is also treated as method call on a *raw type* as if it has been declared like:

```
public void test(ArrayList list) {}
```

Thus no compilation errors happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the factory builder should take in an `ExpirePolicy` instead of `Serializable` for creating the factory. Changing the signature to

```
class FactoryBuilder {
    public static <T extends ExpirePolicy> Factory<T> of(T instance){
        System.out.println(instance.getClass());
        return new Factory<T>() {};
    }
}
```

enables using

```
class C<K,V> extends BaseConfiguration<K,V> {

      public C<K,V> setExpiration(){
          super.setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.of(getExpirePolicy()));
          return this;
      }

      private ExpirePolicy getExpirePolicy(){
          return new ExpirePolicy() {};
      }
}
```

without extra casts.

The second implementation of `C` compiles, but with warnings, because it's using raw types.

Comment: The question is not in what factory builder should take (its obviously). The question is **why `The second implementation of C compiles`** The generic of Factory is not depends on <K,V>... Additionally i can say, that you ca fix problem by adding `extends Serializable` to `ExpirePolicy`

Comment: It compiles (with warnings) because the second version ignores any generic type declarations and uses raw types instead. Why are you expecting it to _not compile_?

Comment: I am expecting that it would not compile because type parameters <K, V> in the BaseConfiguration<K,V> class doesn't affect type of 'factory' argument of setExpiryPolicyFactory method, so even in the second implementation of C there must still be an compile-time error. And we still couldn't call setExpiryPolicyFactory(Factory<? extends ExpirePolicy> factory) with instance of Factory<Serializable>